# How can I fix the " no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout" error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, output

`|55|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << DetermineElapsedTime(((const MyTime*)(& tm)), ((const MyTime*)(& tm2)))'|`

I realize that cout does not understand the how to output that correctly. However, at this moment neither do I.

Here is my code. The issue is all the way near the bottom.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;
struct MyTime { int hours, minutes, seconds; };
MyTime DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime *t1, const MyTime *t2);

const int hourSeconds = 3600;
const int minSeconds = 60;
const int dayHours = 24;

MyTime DetermineElapsedTime(const MyTime *t1, const MyTime *t2)
{
    long hourDiff = ((t2->hours * hourSeconds) - (t1->hours * hourSeconds));
    int timeHour = hourDiff / hourSeconds;
    long minDiff = ((t2->minutes * minSeconds) - (t1->minutes * minSeconds));
    int timeMin = minDiff / minSeconds;
    int timeSec = (t2->seconds - t1 -> seconds);
    MyTime time;
    time.hours = timeHour;
    time.minutes = timeMin;
    time.seconds = timeSec;
    return time;
}


main(void)
{
    char delim1, delim2;
    MyTime tm, tm2;
    cout << "Input two formats for the time. Separate each with a space. Ex: hr:min:sec\n";
    cin >> tm.hours >> delim1 >> tm.minutes >> delim2 >> tm.seconds;
    cin >> tm2.hours >> delim1 >> tm2.minutes >> delim2 >> tm2.seconds;

    if (tm2.hours <= tm.hours && tm2.minutes <= tm.minutes && tm2.seconds <= tm.seconds)
        {
            tm2.hours += dayHours;
        }
    cout << DetermineElapsedTime(&tm, &tm2); // Problem is here

    return 0;

}
```

Also, any hints on how I can output the time elapse as 01:01:01 if needed? I know about setfill.. somewhat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyTime is a struct. Overload the << operator for this type

```
std::ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const MyTime& m) {
       os << m.hours << ":" << m.minutes << ":" << m.seconds;
       return os;
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned this yet but that goes in the elapse function?

Comment: No, you define it outside of the main and elapse function. It will match the MyTime type and describes how to use your MyTime type with the ostream (cout is an ostream).

Comment: Thanks. This helped, didn't understand at first but other poster helped me.

Comment: Any idea on how I can use setfill with that?

Comment: I think you can just use it inside the operator overload: os << setfill ('x') << m.hours << ...

Comment: Exactly what I was trying. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare stream operator for your `MyTime` struct:

```
struct MyTime
{
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& sm)
    {
         sm << "hours: "<<hours<<" seconds: "<<seconds<<" minutes: "<<minutes;
         return sm;
    }
};
```

If you cant change struct then declare free operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& sm, const MyTime& my_time)
{
     sm << "hours: "<<my_time.hours<<" seconds: "<<my_time.seconds<<" minutes: "<<my_time.minutes;
     return sm;
}
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to change the struct

Comment: Even if you could change `MyTime`, why would you make it a friend? All f `MyTime`'s members are public anyway.

Comment: Have a look at this simple example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Nice find, I will try to check for setfill. i am almost done!